# Packaged Jar unable to read files from mapped network drive (Windows)

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Spring Boot application which reads files in folders on a mapped network drive, i.e. m:/PRODUCTION

The problem is, when I execute the jar file, my debugging output shows that no files exist in the folder, even though the folder is full of a files.

I have IntelliJ installed on the same machine, and if I run the application from it's source code, it works absolutely fine.

The method I have that reads filename to an array is;

```
private File[] getFilesInPath(String path) {
        File folder = new File(path);
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        if (listOfFiles != null) {
            Arrays.sort(listOfFiles, Comparator.comparingLong(File::lastModified));
        }

        return listOfFiles;
    }
```

Then, I call this function from a number of places in the application, here's an example;

```
public void manuallyProcessAttritionData(List<Line> lines) {
        Handler handler = new AttritionHandler().setLines(lines).setService(this);

        String pathToProcess = dataFolder + attritionFolder;
        log.debug("Processing path: " + pathToProcess);
        File[] listOfFiles = getFilesInPath(pathToProcess);
        if (listOfFiles != null) {
            log.debug("Number of files to process: " + listOfFiles.length);
            for (File file : listOfFiles) {
                handler.processFile(file);
            }
        } else {
            log.debug("No files to process");
        }
    }
```

The output from running the above is;

```
Processing ATTRITION data...
Processing path: m:/PRODUCTION
No files to process
...Finished processing ATTRITION data
```

I've confirmed the path is correct, running the following commands from the command line works fine and there are files in the result;

```
cd m:\PRODUCTION
M:\PRODUCTION>
```

Does anyone know of a reason why the folder can be read perfectly find from the application running in IntelliJ, but not when packaged as a JAR file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your development account Intellij has access to this drive where as the account which started this spring-boot doesn't have access to it.

I would suggest using full path instead of a mapped network path.

Comment: I've running the jar file from a .bat file which I'm running as administrator. I will try using the full network path though.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no difference in running the code from intelliJ or running it from the built jar. But there may be other factors comming into play. Maybe you run intelliJ with a different user than the jvm that runs the jar? I propose the following steps to resolve the issue:

**1. Use the `Path` Class to avoid platform specific problems (eg. file separators)**
Instead of

```
    new File("path/to/my/directory");
```

you should use

```
    Paths.get("path", "to", "my", "directory").toFile()
```

or

```
    Paths.get("path/to/my/directory").toFile()
```

**2. Check the file attributes**
Use the code below to investigate if the directory exists, if you have the correct permissions etc.

```
Path directory = Paths.get("e:/TEMP");
System.out.println("Absolute Path of directory: " + directory.toAbsolutePath());
System.out.println("Directory exists: " + directory.toFile().exists());
System.out.println("Directory is a directory: " + directory.toFile().isDirectory());
System.out.println("Directory isReadable: " + directory.toFile().canRead());
System.out.println("Directory isWriteable: " + directory.toFile().canWrite());
```

this should output something like:

```
Absolute Path of directory: e:\TEMP
Directory exists: true
Directory is a directory: true
Directory isReadable: true
Directory isWriteable: true
```